# How to add strings values to arrayListOf in Kotlin?

Tags: java, android, string, kotlin, arraylist

I am translating an app in Kotlin using two different files of strings but in arrayListOf there are string like this:

```
var language = arrayListOf<String>(
    "Profile Settings",
    "About Us",
    "Rate Us",
    "Language",
    "Push Notification",
    "Terms of Service",
    "Privacy Policy",
    "Help (FAQ)",
    "Support"
)
```

i want to change it to be responsive to the language chosen
for example:

```
var language = arrayListOf<String>(
    "@strings/Profile Settings",
    
)
```

is it possible to do it from arrayListOf? or there is another way to do it?

Answer (score 2):

`@string` is XML syntax for a String resource. To access the String resources in Kotlin, you use `R.string.` The `R` values are Ints, so you need to convert them to Strings, which you can do using `map` to avoid having to repeat code for every element.

```
val language: List<String> = listOf(
    R.string.profileSettings,
    //...
).map { requireContext().getString(it) }
```

If you do this in a property instead of in a function, you need to wrap the whole declaration in `by lazy` because the context is not available until the Fragment is attached.

In an Activity, you can omit `requireContext().` since the Activity itself is its own Context, so it can be shortened to `.map(::getString)`.

Comment: i keep getting this error "Unexpected tokens (use ';' to separate expressions on the same line)" after trying your solution

Comment: You must have a syntax issue. Maybe you used the wrong kind of brackets.

Answer (score 1):

You can re-write the Array-list like this:

```
var language = arrayListOf<String>(
   getString(R.string.profile_settings),
   .... 
)
```